# NSubstitute - mock throwing an exception in method returning Task

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task, nsubstitute

Using [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io), how do you mock an exception being thrown in a method returning a Task?

Let's say our method signature looks something like this:

```
Task<List<object>> GetAllAsync();
```

Here's how NSubstitute docs say to mock throwing exceptions for non-void return types. But this doesn't compile :(

```
myService.GetAllAsync().Returns(x => { throw new Exception(); });
```

So how do you accomplish this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Actually, the accepted answer mocks a synchronous exception being thrown, that is not the *real* `async` behavior. The correct way to mock is:

```
var myService = Substitute.For<IMyService>();
myService.GetAllAsync()
         .Returns(Task.FromException<List<object>>(new Exception("some error")));
```

Let's say you had this code and `GetAllAsync()`

```
try
{
    var result = myService.GetAllAsync().Result;
    return result;
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    // whatever, do something here
}
```

The `catch` would only be executed with `Returns(Task.FromException>()`, not with the accepted answer since it synchronously throws the exception.

Comment: No, try it with real code (not mocks), if your `async` method throws `MyCustomException` for example, an `AggregationException` will be received if you use `.Result`. If you use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, then you'll get the real `MyCustomException`. Your way would always throws `MyCustomException`, regardless of how it's being used.

Comment: Task.FromException<List<object>> List<object> type is important, or there will be CouldNotSetReturnDueToTypeMismatchException

Comment: This is the real correct answer if you want to catch the exception, for example , in a ContinueWith (only on faulted). 

fileProcessor.ProcessAsync(path, ct).ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    AggregateException flattened = task?.Exception?.Flatten();
                    flattened?.Handle(ex =>
                    {
                        Log.Error("Error on the file processing : {exception}", ex.ToString());
                        return true;
                    });
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

Comment: I get an error when I try to do this. Looks like NSubstitute doesn't like that I'm returning a type (error) that doesn't match my return (success response). Maybe this was introduced recently. Any suggestions? NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToTypeMismatchException : Can not return value of type Task`1 for IOrdersResource.SubmitAsync (expected type Task`1).

Comment: I've got an error when I try to do this. Cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<object>>' to 'System.Func<NSubstitute.Core.CallInfo, System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Guid>

Answer (score 31):

This worked:

```
using NSubstitute.ExceptionExtensions;

myService.GetAllAsync().Throws(new Exception());
```

Comment: This is a synchronous exception, see my answer for the correct way.

Comment: The biggest problem with this is that the exception is thrown at the wrong time. `var t = AsyncMethod(); await t;`. With an async method the exception is thrown when awaiting the task, your approach throws the exception immediately. What kind of exception is thrown depends on a lot of things.

Comment: This is incorrect. It does not simulate what would happen in a real world scenario. Do [this instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027096/542251)

Comment: @Liam if really want to simulate a real scenario do integration test, for the unit test it works perfectly.

Comment: As other mentions, this doesn't work when you are doing stuff with the task, such as `ContinueWith`. However, it will most likely give the same result if you're simply awaiting the task.

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me:

```
myService.GetAllAsync().Returns(Task.Run(() => ThrowException()));

private List<object> ThrowException()
{
        throw new Exception();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case it worked as follows

```
_substiture.GetAsync<SomeType?>("").ThrowsAsyncForAnyArgs(new CustomException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "some message"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple line worked for me:

```
Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(async () => await _service.MyAsyncFunction());
```